# Using ifelse in R when one of the options produces NAs?

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I want to vectorize a function that relies on checking a condition and depending on whether this condition is TRUE or FALSE, return the outcome of one of two functions, respectively. The problem is that, when the condition is FALSE, the first function cannot be evaluated. Then, ifelse returns the correct values but it also produces a warning. I would like to produce a function that does not produce warnings.

I have tried `ifelse()`, but it does not work. I was expecting that this command would skip the evaluation of the first function when the condition is FALSE.

Here is an illustrative piece of R code

```
p = c(-1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1)

ifelse(p>0, sqrt(p), p^2)
```

which returns

```
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
Warning message:
In sqrt(p) : NaNs produced
```

As you can see, the outcome is correct but, for some reason, it evaluates the function at the first function when condition is FALSE. Thus, I would like to somehow avoid this issue.

Comment: A warning is not the same as an error...

Comment: @CPak I agree! That is why I do not call them errors in my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can create a `numeric` vector and then fill the elements based on the condition put forward by 'p'

```
out <- numeric(length(p))
out[p > 0] <- sqrt(p[p > 0])
out[p <= 0] <- p[p <= 0]^2
```

---

With `ifelse` we need to have all arguments of the same `length`.  According to `?ifelse`

> ifelse(test, yes, no)
>
> A vector of the same length and attributes (including dimensions and
>   "class") as test and data values from the values of yes or no

What happens is that we do both the calculations on the entire vector and replace the values of 'p' based on the `test` condition.  For `sqrt`, the negative values definitely gives warning and output as `NaN`.  While the `NaN` elements don't show up in the output, the warning was already printed.  The warning is a friendly one, but can be suppressed with `suppressWarnings`

Comment: This sounds like a great option. Do you think I should just avoid `ifelse`? This is, is there a fundamental reason for not using it in cases where one of the options is not defined in all cases?

Comment: It's hard to give a blanket statement on the wisdom of "avoiding `ifelse`" in the general case.  There are times when I use it, and times when I avoid it.  Considerations I consider are 1. how quickly do I need the code to run (related to, how large are my data), and 2. do I want to avoid warning messages like this one (or is `suppressWarnings` enough), and 3. would one of my expressions create an error if used in `ifelse`.

Answer (score 4):

Avoidance through `ifelse` probably isn't possible.  My understanding of the `ifelse` process is

1. Create a vector of values based on the expression in `yes`
2. Create a vector of values based on the expression in `no`
3. Use the result of `test` to decide whether each element comes from `yes` or `no`.

If an error will occur in either `yes` or `no`, `ifelse` will fail.

To get around this, you need to only evaluate expressions where they will succeed. (such as in akrun's answer, a variant of which is given here for completeness)

```
p = c(-1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1)

condition <- p > 0

result <- numeric(length(p))

result[g1] <- sqrt(p[condition])
result[!g1] <- p[condition]^2
```