# Strange behavior of ifelse() in R: when are the values evaluated?

Tags: r, if-statement, nan, sqrt

I have the following data:

```
df = data.frame(
  stat = c('mean', 'var'),
  value = c(-9, 10))
```

Let say I want to take the square of 'value' if 'stat' is "var", and do nothing if not.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(
   value = ifelse(stat=='var', sqrt(value), value))
```

I get a warning:

```
Warning message:
In sqrt(-9) : NaNs produced
```

Why am I getting the warning? The value sqrt(-9) is not supposed to be computed
as 'value' is "mean"

Comment: Need complex numbers. Can't get -root

Comment: It does not answer the question. The ifelse() is supposed to compute the sqrt() only if value == 'var'. If not, it is supposed to let the value as is. So it is supposed the compute sqrt(10) BUT NOT sqrt(-9).

Comment: Great explanation in the linked question.

Comment: I just updated my answer below to show how ifelse could be used without external packages.

Answer (score 1):

As per the `ifelse` documentation

```
 If ‘yes’ or ‘no’ are too short, their elements are recycled.
 ‘yes’ will be evaluated if and only if any element of ‘test’ is
 true, and analogously for ‘no’.
```

You have interpreted this to mean that yes or no will be bypassed in an *elementwise* manner.

However, it seems that this is not what the doc means. It means that, unless *all* elements in the test are either true or false, then evaluations will occur.

Meaning that, as long as your test has at least one true, and at least one false, then both yes and no will be precomputed for each element in the test, and only after that element has been evaluated, the appropriate response is selected.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question "when are the values evaluated?" is: it depends.

If all of the elements are `TRUE`, then the third argument won't be evaluated at all. If all of the arguments are `FALSE`, then the second argument won't be evaluated.

However, if there is at least one `TRUE` and one `FALSE`, then they are both *fully* evaluated.

```
ifelse(c(TRUE, TRUE), "good", stop("error"))
#> [1] "good" "good"

ifelse(c(FALSE, FALSE), "good", stop("error"))
#> Error in ifelse(c(FALSE, FALSE), "good", stop("error")) : error

ifelse(c(TRUE, FALSE), "good", stop("error"))
#> Error in ifelse(c(TRUE, FALSE), "good", stop("error")) : error
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need a package to do this:

```
df = data.frame(stat = c('mean', 'var'),
                value = c(-9, 10))
computed = df[df$stat == 'var','value'] %>% sqrt
```

if you want the original value to be overwritten then instead of the second row:

```
df[df$stat == 'var','value'] = df[df$stat == 'var','value'] %>% sqrt
```

if you want to use native `ifelse` then:

```
ifelse(df$stat =="var",sqrt(df$value),df$value)
```

Comment: you have one too many quotes in your `computed` statement

Answer (score 0):

I have been referred to that question in a comment:

[Using ifelse in R when one of the options produces NAs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56838253/using-ifelse-in-r-when-one-of-the-options-produces-nas)

To cite the author:
"What happens is that we do both the calculations on the entire vector and replace the values of 'p' based on the test condition. For sqrt, the negative values definitely gives warning and output as NaN. While the NaN elements don't show up in the output, the warning was already printed. The warning is a friendly one, but can be suppressed with suppressWarnings"